# Decisionproblem on Strings

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given is a set S = {s<sub>1</sub>, ..., s<sub>m</sub>} where each s<sub>i</sub> is a string of length k over the alphabet {0,1,?}.

I am looking for an efficient algorithm solving the following decision problem: 
Is it true that for each 1 ≤ a < b ≤ k there is a string s<sub>i</sub> in S s.t. s<sub>i</sub>(a) = 0 and s<sub>i</sub>(b) = 1 or s<sub>i</sub>(a) = 1 and s<sub>i</sub>(b) = 0, where s<sub>i</sub>(a) denotes the a-th character in string s<sub>i</sub>.

I am looking for a sublinear time algorithm in m, so something like O(\sqrt(m)f(k)) would be the goal.

Comment: The original formatting of this question makes me sad that StackOverflow, unlike [CSTheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com), doesn't support [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). :(

Comment: Yes, the formatting is downright painful to read.

Comment: I changed it, sorry I wasn't aware that SO doesn't support MathJax

Comment: Well that is much easier to read, and it is a different problem than I solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done in less than linear time, unless prior offline processing is allowed.

Basically the first string that satisfies your criterion will be the last one you consider.  And you might have to consider all m-1 others first.

Comment: But this runs in time proportional to m*k no?

Comment: Changed answer in response to changed question.  Original question had inscrutable formatting and asked for sub-quadratic, not sub linear.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Bitfield your character space (`0 == 0x1`, `1 == 0x2`,...), then take the first *N* characters of each string in *S* and add their transformed representations, XOR the total against `0x3,...`, and see if it evaluates zero.

For faster traversal than `O(n)`, use this to form a binary search tree or heap (`O(lg n)` fetch), or a hash (`O(1)` fetch). If *S* is guaranteed to be sorted, this becomes even easier.

At least, if I understand your question properly. For better, more theoretic results with bounded mathematical complexity and proofs, [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [CSTheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) are the go-to locations.

Comment: Well that is answering a problem different than I answered.  I wonder which one the OP actually meant...